# How to assign a dictionary to a QML property?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a custom QML object written in C++ where one property is of the type `QVariantMap`, so it should be compatible with Javascript objects.

However, I have some troubles actually assigning a JS object:

```
Uploader {
    sample: selectSampleButton.fileUrl
    parameters: {
        x: '3'
        y: "String"
    }
}
```

Is this even possible like this? One possiblity I found that works is to assign it in Javascript:

```
uploader.parameters = {x: "Test"};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it in parentheses, otherwise it is parsed as a [binding expression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#static-values-and-binding-expression-values) :

```
Uploader {
    sample: selectSampleButton.fileUrl
    parameters: ({
        x: '3'
        y: "String"
    })
}
```

Comment: It is still parsed as a binding expression, however this time returning a JS object.

Comment: @ddriver: That means if I use properties inside the JS object, it gets automatically updated, right? I'll have to test what happens if I manually add properties to the dict in JS. My guess is they are overwritten each time a bound property changes.

Comment: That should not be the case, as the JSObject won't  signal a change of one of it's properties. If you want to have this, you would need to use a `QtObject`. `paramteres: QtObject { property int x: 3; onXChanged: idofparent.parametersChanged() }`

Comment: @GeorgSchölly - no they will not, internal changes will not trigger the notify signal. It will only trigger if you assign a different object to the property. Or if you make changes and then explicitly emit the signal to force reevaluation.

Comment: @ddriver, @derM: I'm sorry, I didn't clearly express what I was thinking about. Let's say I have this: `parameters: ({ x: someOtherObject.prop })` and `someOtherObject.prop` changes, the `parameters` object gets recalculated. If I new use JS to add another attribute: `uploader.parameters['y']`, this might get overwritten.

Comment: Bindings will not automatically reevaluate if properties of JS objects change internally. What enables this automatic behavior is property notifications, and those are available only for QML properties, not for JS properties. If you have a `property var someJSObject` and you `someJSObject.prop = newValue` this will not reevaluate bindings which use `someJSObject.prop`. You can force that by manually emitting `someJSObjectChanged()`. I assume by "recalculated" you mean bindings. There is nothing else to recalcuate.

Comment: No, there is no *recalculation* (or *recreation* of a new JSObject). The object `someJSObject` is still the same `someJSObject` just with one of it's properties changed. That is why there is no signal `parametersChanged`. Further the properties of a `JSObject` have no *change notifications*, so there won't be no signal: `someJSObject.propChanged`. As there is no change notification, bindings to `someJSObject.prop` won't be updated. (I removed my comment, that suggested that. I was surprised by a test result I had, but the reason was different, so my conclusion was wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed set of keys you could create a "grouped property", e.g. like `font` or `anchors`

The type of a grouped property is just a `QObject` derived class with respective `Q_PROPERTY` declaration and an instance of that is used by the main class, in your case the class behin `Uploader` as a `Q_PROPERTY` of a pointer to the new type.

Roughly like this

```
class UploaderParameters : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int x MEMBER m_x NOTIFY xChanged)
};

class Uploader : public QObject
{
    Q_PROPERTY(UploaderParameters* parameters MEMBER m_parameters CONSTANT)
};
```

in QML

```
Uploader {
    parameters.x: 3
}
```

or

```
Uploader {
    parameters {
        x: 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the parameters are not fixed. I could of course use something similar to `ListElement`, but that seems to be overkill.